# Instant messaging system in Web App and Mobile Native App

Tags: asp.net, mobile, messaging

I am searching for some messaging systems or frameworks which are readily to be integrated into .NET web application, which is similar to that found in Facebook and Google, but without voice and video call. Also it can support Mobile Native App. Are there any options for this system?

Any answer would be highly appreciated.